Build a docker plugin multi architecture?
I did lookup the docker engine plugin docs and I did not find a single sample anywhere how to build a multi architecture plugin. I need make an amd64 plugin work for both amd64 and arm64. Is there anything out there what I can study? It is not clear to me if this is possible at all.

Looked at the docs more, and plugins appear to be not multi platform compatible from the outset. One can work around that by publishing tags with architecture appended or so.
